# Avoiding D3.js "groupData is undefined" errors when selecting on fixed field name of form d.value

Tags: arrays, null, d3.js

Probably trivial, but I seem to have a nested data situation for which I can find no guidance. I have an array representing an time progression (index) for which data is only intermittently available:

```
elem[..]
elem[55].path[..]
elem[56]
elem[57]
elem[58].path[..]
elem[59]
elem[60].path[..]
elem[..]
```

Empty data points are null:

```
elem[count] = null;
```

..whereas, pending further use, path elements are initialised using:

```
elem[count].path = [];
```

A large data set is gathered. In the first of the following two blocks of code, I select the array indexes

```
classes[chan_index].elem_num_container = "elem_num_container" + "_" + comp_id + "_" + chan_index;

chan_selector.elem_num_container[chan_index] = chan_selector.vis_container[chan_index]
.selectAll(classes[chan_index].elem_num_container)
.data(function(d, i) {
    return d;
})
.enter()
.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return classes[chan_index].elem_num_container;
});
```

Given so many null elements, in the second block (below), the nested d.path understandably provokes a "groupData is undefined" error.

```
classes[chan_index].path_container = "path_container" + "_" + comp_id + "_" + chan_index;

chan_selector.path_container[chan_index] = chan_selector.elem_num_container[chan_index]
.selectAll(classes[chan_index].path_container)
.data(function(d, i) {
    return d.path;
})
.enter()
.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return classes[chan_index].path_container;
});
```

Basically it comes down to selecting data based on the "d" parameter, followed by a nested selection on "d.value". While preserving the index, I need to side-step the error and select d.path elements, where they exist.

I see plenty nested JSON data examples, but nothing applicable to this case.

Blocked, and grateful for any help..
Thx

Comment: Where are you using the variable `groupData`?

Comment: Is selection filtering applicable here? Something like chan_selector.elem_num_container[chan_index].selectAll(classes[chan_index].path_container).filter(function(d) { return typeof(d.path) !== "undefined";})...

Comment: @LarsKotthoff groupData is not accessed, but mentioned in the error message.

Comment: So where does this `groupData` come from?

Comment: @Superboggly I will be using the indexes -including some with no data- in transitions. According to the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter), "if you want to preserve the index (which I do), use select instead".

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff According to Mike Bostock, "that error means that you're passing undefined (or a function that returns undefined) to the data operator".

Comment: Can you filter the undefined/null values before passing to the first `.data()` function?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I've tried select, selectAll and filter variants of the following sandwiched between the origin selectAll() and data() calls:

.select(function(d) { if (typeof(d.path) !== "null") {return d.path; };})

Logging shows
1) selectAll leapfrogs both blocks (nothing fired). 2) Both the select and filter variants find the first few instances of d.path but stumble on null d.path values in the second block, now returning "TypeError: d is null". Moreover, if those null datapoints are set to the empty string or array, the same variants provoke a d3-internal "groupData is undefined" error.

Comment: I mean something like `.filter(function(d) { return d !== null; })`.

Comment: Tried d !== null and typeof(d) === 'object' in select(), filter() and, in a new, intermediate code block, data(), but still hitting groupData errors.

Comment: Where are you actually setting your data initially? Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/mkJNf/) do anything like what you want?

Answer (score 1):

From the responses above, elimination of null elements was clearly held to be feasible, throwing doubt on incoming data (checked: all ok) and d3 processing hierarchy (malformed: two processing branches hung on to the same node, one propagating data, the other -the branch in question above- not).

In response, separated the two branches from their parent with new, interstitial svg:g container structures. Result: data on both branches.

Then, as suggested in the responses above, with d.path, I added a filter on the processing branch in question (ie between first and second code blocks in the original question), in the form:

```
chan_selector.temp[chan_index] = chan_selector.elem_num_container[chan_index]
.filter(function(d) { return typeof(d.path) === 'object'; });
```

Strangely (given claimed impact of filter on indexing) it works, giving the accustomed d3 eyecandy. :-)

Thanks to Superboggly and Lars Kotthoff for the valuable help and patience.